# Python Request not getting all data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape data from *Google translate* for educational purpose.

Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/9860ef03065f2c0be557dbae509fea14#file-phonetizer-py)

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=en&text=hello
#tlid-transliteration-content transliteration-content full

class Phonetizer:
    def __init__(self,sentence : str,language_ : str = 'en'):
        self.words=sentence.split()
        self.language=language_
    def get_phoname(self):
        for word in self.words:
            print(word)
            url="https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl="+self.language+"&tl="+self.language+"&text="+word
            print(url)
            req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0'})
            webpage = urlopen(req).read()
            f= open("debug.html","w+")
            f.write(webpage.decode("utf-8"))
            f.close()
            #print(webpage)
            bsoup = BeautifulSoup(webpage,'html.parser')
            phonems = bsoup.findAll("div", {"class": "tlid-transliteration-content transliteration-content full"})
            print(phonems)
            #break
```

The problem is when gives me the html, there is no `tlid-transliteration-content transliteration-content full` class, of css.

But using inspect, I have found that, phoneme are inside this css class, here take a snap :

[image: google_translate_scrap]

I have saved the html, and [here](https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/9860ef03065f2c0be557dbae509fea14#file-debug-html) it is, take a look, no  `tlid-transliteration-content transliteration-content full` is present and it not like other google translate page, it is not complete. I have heard google blocks crawler, bot, spyder. And it can be easily detected by their system, so I added the additional header, but still I can't access the whole page.

**How can I do so ? Access the whole page and read all data from google translate page?**

*[Want to contribute on this project?](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/phonetizer-google)*

I have tried this code below :

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
lang = "en"
word = "hello"
url="https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl="+lang+"&tl="+lang+"&text="+word
async def get_url():
    r = await asession.get(url)
    print(r)
    return r
results = asession.run(get_url)
for result in results:
    print(result.html.url)
    print(result.html.find('#tlid-transliteration-content'))
    print(result.html.find('#tlid-transliteration-content transliteration-content full'))
```

**It gives me nothing, till now.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this happens because some javascript generated content are rendered by the browser on page load, but what you see is the final DOM, after all kinds of manipulation happened by javascript (adding content). To solve this you would need to use `selenium` but it has multiple downsides like speed and memory issues. A more modern and better way, in my opinion, is to use [requests-html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) where it will replace both `bs4` and `urllib` and it has a `render` method as mentioned in the documentation.

Here is a sample code using `requests_html`, just keep in mind what you trying to print is not `utf8` so you might run into some issues printing it on some editors like sublime, it ran fine using cmd.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get("https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=en&text=hello")
r.html.render()
css = ".source-input .tlid-transliteration-content"
print(r.html.find(css, first=True).text)
# output: heˈlō,həˈlō
```

Comment: I have tried using `requests_html`, but it gives me empty list or array when I'm trying to select a CSS element, can you help me here?

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Here you go, just added a sample code that runs fine

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest you to use the Google Translate API instead of scraping google page. The API is a hundred times easier, hassle-free and a legal and conventional way of doing this.

However, if you want to fix this, here is the solution.
You are not dealing with Bot detection here. Google's bot detection is so strong it would just open the google `re-captcha` page and not even show your desired web-page.
The problem here is that the results of translation are not returned using the URL you have used. This URL just displays the basic translator page, the results are fetched later by `javascript` and are shown on the page after the page has been loaded. The javascript is not processed by `python-requests` and this is why the class doesn't even exist in the `web-page` you are accessing.

The solution is to trace the packets and detect which `URL` is being used by `javascript` to fetch results. Fortunately, I have found the found the desired `URL` for this purpose.
If you request `https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=webapp&sl=en&tl=fr&hl=en&dt=at&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=gt&source=bh&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=1&tk=327718.241137&q=goodmorning`, you will get the response of translator as JSON. You can parse the JSON to get the desired results. 
Here, you can face Bot detection here which can straight away throw an HTTP 403 error.

You can also use `selenium` to process `javascript` and give you results. Following changes inyour code can fix it using `selenium`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=en&text=hello
#tlid-transliteration-content transliteration-content full

class Phonetizer:
    def __init__(self,sentence : str,language_ : str = 'en'):
        self.words=sentence.split()
        self.language=language_
    def get_phoname(self):
        for word in self.words:
            print(word)
        url="https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl="+self.language+"&tl="+self.language+"&text="+word
        print(url)
        #req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0'})
        #webpage = urlopen(req).read()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        webpage = driver.page_source
        driver.close()
        f= open("debug.html","w+")
        f.write(webpage.decode("utf-8"))
        f.close()
        #print(webpage)
        bsoup = BeautifulSoup(webpage,'html.parser')
        phonems = bsoup.findAll("div", {"class": "tlid-transliteration-content transliteration-content full"})
        print(phonems)
        #break
```

Comment: I have tried your way, using `requests_html`, but it gives me nothing when I'm trying to select a CSS element, can you help me here?

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad What does _gives me nothing_ mean, exactly? What CSS element are you talking about?

Comment: `tlid-transliteration-content transliteration-content full` css element, `div` of this class ... it gives me [], array of length 0 @AlexanderCécile

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Could you try the CSS selector method, see if that works? Writing the classes in the `class_` parameter instead of under `attrs` might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should scrape this page with `Javascript` support, since the content you're looking for "hiding" inside `<script>` tag, which `urllib` does not render.
I would suggest to use `Selenium` or other equivalent framework.
Take a look here: [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)